# Check for Header and Footer in a Flow File in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to Apache NiFi and I am trying to solve the following scenario:

I have a  file in the following format:

`@RTOajvnodsnvodsvdsonbbvoiroi
uvdsoiuvoibvds
@RBCinbdiuvidsnb`

Each line is terminated by a new line character. The first and last lines are the header and footer lines. I need to check whether the header and footer lines have @RTO and @RBC respectively or not. If yes, I would need to route the flow file.

I am trying to use the `RouteOnContent` processor to achieve this, using the regular expression `(@RTO)[\\S\\s\\w\\W]*(@RBC)[\\S\\s\\w\\W]*`. I tested it in Java and it works out, but it does not work in NiFi.

The processor properties screenshot is attached- [image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the config of your RouteContent processor?

Comment: I have added an image of the processor properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex isn't quite sufficient to match the newlines. I've created a [template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/c7e549e424a508b967c91d2f59aa4a42) with a working version (`\A(@RTO)(.*\n)*(@RBC).*\z`). This template generates flowfiles and populates them with either:

- The header and footer flags as you provided above
- Only the header
- Only the footer
- Neither

and then routes them accordingly. I took your description to be "header and footer present" or "other", but you can modify to fit your needs.

Comment: This is not what I am exactly trying to do. I am creating a flow File using Get File which has the data. If the data has the header and footer I need to put that file to a certain location. So, my flow would be Get File -> RouteOnContent -> PutFile. The problem is that RouteOnContent is not working as expected with the regular expression.

Comment: Saharsh, I didn't know where you were getting the file from so I just generated it in NiFi, but `GetFile` should be fine. Are you sure there are no weird encoding issues? I copied the text you provided in the question and used the regex I listed in my answer, and it successfully routed 1/4 of the flowfiles (the ones with both header and footer) to a different `LogAttribute` processor than the rest. Are you getting all of the flowfiles routed to the "unmatched" `LogAttribute`?

Comment: Andy, the data I provided was just a format of the data. I am running it on the original file and I am not getting the output that I need. All flow files are getting routed to unmatched. I dont think there is any encoding issue too.

Comment: Can you provide actual examples of the data?

Comment: I would not be able to give the actual problems of the data. However, I solved it by checking first for header and then checking for Footer in another processor.